# Data binding does not support include as a direct child of a merge element

Tags: android, android-databinding

I am trying use data binding to my existing project. As part of that, initially I am trying get rid of all findViewById() method.

Now the issue is, I have a layout as below:-

```
<merge >
<include
    android:id="@+id/my_login_process_view"
    layout="@layout/content_my_message_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</merge>
```

after adding android binding to this layout (adding layout as parent tag) it throws error as below.

*Data binding does not support include as a direct child of a merge element*

I have followed android official guide [Android data binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html).

I am just trying get rid of findViewById for above layout file.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: what do u want to merge? I can only see one layout inside merge.

Comment: 'content_my_message_view.xml' is linear layout file that has some text and image views and I am using this layout in other layouts too. So, I made a separate layout and used include. <merge> tag is I am dynamically replacing the views so I used merge tag. In summery , merge tag is  for the views that will be inflated here at runtime . So, inside merge I have used include tag so, that I can load  content_my_message_view.xml at run time.

Comment: as the name implies u need more than one to merge sth in practice

Comment: also merge is not supported w.r.t. to the official doc. see my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The link you provided obviously says that it is not supported.

> Data binding **does not support** include as a direct child of a merge
>   element. For example, the following layout is not supported:
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>         xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
>    <data>
>        <variable name="user" type="com.example.User"/>
>    </data>
>    <merge>
>        <include layout="@layout/name"
>            bind:user="@{user}"/>
>        <include layout="@layout/contact"
>            bind:user="@{user}"/>
>    </merge>
> </layout>
> ```

According to the official doc what it works is the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
   <data>
       <variable name="user" type="com.example.User"/>
   </data>
   <LinearLayout
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">
       <include layout="@layout/name"
           bind:user="@{user}"/>
       <include layout="@layout/contact"
           bind:user="@{user}"/>
   </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```